# How to show progress during upload asynchronously with WASM

Tags: go, webassembly, go-wasm

I am currently using Go WASM to upload a file to a server. During the upload it shall emit a call to update the upload progress in the UI.

I am currently using the following struct to have an indication of the progress:

```
type progressReporter struct {
    r                 io.Reader
    fileSizeEncrypted int64
    sent              int64
    file              js.Value
}

func (pr *progressReporter) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := pr.r.Read(p)
    pr.sent = pr.sent + int64(n)
    pr.report()
    return n, err
}

func (pr *progressReporter) report() {
    go js.Global().Get("dropzoneObject").Call("emit", "uploadprogress", pr.file, pr.sent*100/pr.fileSizeEncrypted, pr.sent)
}
```

The upload happens in a promise:

```
func UploadChunk(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        [...]
    handler := js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        resolve := args[0]
        reject := args[1]

        go func() {
            [...]

            body := new(bytes.Buffer)
            writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
            part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("file", "encrypted.file")
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            _, err = part.Write(*data)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            err = writer.Close()
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            pReporter := progressReporter{
                    r:                 body,
                    fileSizeEncrypted: fileSize,
                    sent:              offset,
                    file:              jsFile,
                }
            r, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "./uploadChunk", &pReporter)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            r.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
            client := &http.Client{}
            resp, err := client.Do(r)

            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            [...]
        }
}
```

Although the code works fine, all `emit` calls to update the UI are sent after the POST request is finished. Is there any way to have this call asynchronously?

The full source code can be found [here](https://github.com/Forceu/Gokapi/blob/7848ddec46cdbb4c9e77ed94a735126215bf654b/cmd/wasme2e/Main.go)